# BIRT 3.7 runtime. Customizing of PDF fonts and jdbc drivers are not possible anymore?

Tags: java, pdf, jdbc, birt

I'm trying to upgrade BIRT to the latest runtime 3.7.
Looks like that it's impossible to customize PDF fonts! In previous versions it were done in `org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.fonts*/fontsConfig*.xml` files.

In 3.7 `fontsConfig*.xml` files are embedded in BIRT runtime jar file(in my case it's `org.eclipse.birt.runtime_3.7.1.v20110913-1734.jar`). The jar file is signed, think it's necessary for OSGI. So if you change anything in jar, JRE throw checksum error on loading the file. If you remove the signing info, OSGI will not load it (NPE).

Any ideas how could I customize my pdf fonts without rebuilding BIRT runtime?

By the way, I suspect that the same issue presents for jdbc drivers. Above mentioned jar file contains `drivers` folder. Suspect that it's a stub for jdbc drivers from plugin `org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc*`.

Several years ago I asked a question regarding adding PDF fonts from BIRT runtime. It's still unanswered [BIRT: pdf emitter, load/use fonts from relative path or from jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255916/birt-pdf-emitter-load-use-fonts-from-relative-path-or-from-jar-files)

**UPDATE:**

1. regarding pdf fonts, found open bug unresolved in 3.7.1 - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=347431
2. According to http://wiki.eclipse.org/Birt_3.7_Migration_Guide#JDBC_Drivers, jdbc drivres must be in classpath

Comment: The issue was fixed in 3.7.2. Works fine for me :)

Comment: Great solution with configuring fonts on iText directly is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021711/how-to-configure-birt-report-engine-to-use-fonts-directly-from-the-applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the cleanest way to go, but it's possible to edit them inside the jar file. You can remove the signature by deleting META-INF/ECLIPSEF.SF and removing everything from META-INF/MANIFEST.MF that goes after it's main section (filenames and digests...alternatively, remove just sections of the config files). It's not required to have the jar signed (I suppose it depends on security manager's settings, but under default settings it runs fine).